# Magento 2: Form xml default value

Tags: magento2, forms

I have the following form element which gets a list of products and adds them to a select form element

```
<field name="featuredproduct">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><VENDOR>\<MODULE>\Model\Settings\ProductOptions</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Homepage Featured Product</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Settings</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">homepage_featured_product</item>
                <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">-- Please Select --</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">**RETURN VALUE FROM DB**</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

This works, but I need to set the default value from the current value stored in a custom table in the database.

Not sure how I can pass the value in. The custom table has the resource modal etc.

Any help would be great.